# add a data frame as new column in another dataframe based on condition

Tags: dataframe, conditional-statements

Hi guys I will be happy if u can help me with this: I have dataframe with a commun column and I want to add some column from 1 Dataframe based on condition between the commun column in both dataframe let's take an example:

```
 df1

  A         B              C 
 7.0     2019-09-17        1     
 2.0     2019-09-16        1
 4.0     2019-09-18        1
 6.0     2019-09-12        2
 1.0     2019-09-11        2

df2:
  D         E         C 
 Sam       117        1     
 csd       116        2

 the result should be like this 
 df3:
  A         B              C   D    E
 7.0     2019-09-17        1   Sam  117
 2.0     2019-09-16        1   Sam  117
 4.0     2019-09-18        1   Sam  117
 6.0     2019-09-12        2   csd  116
 1.0     2019-09-11        2   csd  116
```

Thx guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perform join operation on C column.